# wrapped convolution in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Very simple question: is there a reasonably simple way of doing wrapped convolution in tensorflow? `tf.nn.conv1d`, `tf.nn.conv2d`, and `tf.convolution` do not appear to have a "wrap" option (unlike `scipy`), but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d it is possible to give the explicit padding to use - will that work?

Comment: @Taw I don't see how it would...